# GRASS GIS: connecting vertices with lines along following Node Number

Tags: grass-gis, vertices, path

**My goal:**

Convert vertices to a poly line describing the general route to have 1 line describing the center line of a river.

**Limitation:**

- The whole process has to be automated.
- The raster can contain gaps.

The initial input is a raster containing a scan of a proposed river. This scan is of very low resolution (see yellow resulting pixels in picture). I have processed this as follows:

- r.mfilter: High pass filter to sharpen the river using
- r.reclass to reclass all non-river pixels to NULL
- r.to.points to get the vertices of the raster cells

Result:

[image]

Now I want to connect these points to get a generalized (smoothed) line describing the points. I do not have a specific network to do a network analysis. Converting points to lines results in too many lines. 
Also, the nodes number does not correspond completely to the desired trajectory.

Any recommended approach or a different approach altogether to reach the desired result?

@MarkusN:

[image]

Comment: Did you try r.to.vect + https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.to.lines.html (+ v.generalize)?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I have tried it today. I used r.to.vect to convert my raster to lines (you can select the output data type [area, line, point] and then tried to use several algorithms, however the problem, I think, is that the raster cells are disconnected and thus the output will be as well.

Comment: To overcome the disconnected raster cells, you'll have to apply `r.grow.distance` then `r.thin` to get back to a single width raster. And finally `r.to.vect`

Comment: Eventually I ended up using `r.grow` as here I could specify the data type as `CELL` instead of `DCELL` as `r.thin` only works with integers. Thereafter, `v.clean` to remove any dangles. So your suggestion worked well!
!